# C# aggregate with initial value for memo

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `WriteNode` objects. I need to insert an object of a different type to the beginning of the list and multiple all them.

Procedurally, it looks like this:

```
FluentNode dialog = Show();
WriteNode write1 = Write(0, "hello");
WriteNode write2 = Write(0, "world");

FluentNode result = Show() * write1 * write2;
```

Now I want to do this more programmatically.

I have the phrases in a list:

```
List<string> phrases = new List<string> { "hello", "world" };
```

I map over the list to get a list of `WriteNode` objects:

```
IEnumerable<WriteNode> nodes = phrases.Select ((string phrase) => {
        return Write (0, phrase);
})
```

Currently I have the following reduce function to multiply them all together:

```
WriteNode writeNode = nodes.Aggregate ((WriteNode a, WriteNode b) => {
    return (WriteNode)( (WriteNode)a * (WriteNode)b );
});
FluentNode result = dialog * writeNode;
```

But this does not work as intended because I need the first element in the list to be the `dialog` object. Basically this library overloads the `*` operator differently depending on which item is first in the list. So, if my understanding is correct, `dialog * write1 * write2` should work will work while `dialog * (write1 * write2)` will not.

This seems like something the reduce/"Accumulator" function should be able to handle ... is there a way I can pass a  "starting point" for the memo? In ruby it would be something like this:

```
# dialog is the starting value for memo
[word1, word2].reduce(dialog) { |memo, word| memo * word }
```

In Javascript:

```
[word1, word2].reduce( (memo, word) => { return memo * word }, dialog)
```

You get the idea. Is there a way to do this in C# using Linq or another library?

Comment: `Aggregate` has an overload where you pass in a seed value https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx.  But it should be the same type as the result, not sure if that will work in your specific case without seeing the relation between `FluentNode` and `WriteNode`.  Also you can shorten your code like `Select(x =>Write(0,x))`  as the lambdas do not have to have bodies and can infer the type of the input.

Comment: @juharr I guess I forgot to mention, WriteNode inherits from FluentNode. And the result is the same type as the seed, it's like `FluentNode * WriteNodes... = FluentNode`. so thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try

Comment: @juharr thanks a lot for the help. I see now that on the left side of the docs page are the different overloaded definitions. I didn't notice that at first, and didn't see the version that accepts a seed. I got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it the following and it works now.

```
FluentNode result = nodes.Aggregate (
    dialog,
    (FluentNode memo, WriteNode writeNode) => {
        return memo * writeNode;
    }
);
```